# Why empty tuple is returned on calling listbox.curselection() when single click event is triggered in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to play song that has been selected in the listbox. But when i click on any song in the listbox it does not do anything. I tried printing the tuple that is being returned on calling listbox.curselection(). When i click for the first time, empty tuple is returned. On clicking for second time on any song in the listbox, index of previously clicked song is returned.
Here is the code portion -

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeDUx.png)

```
def play_sel(event):
    global index, pause
    sel = listbox.curselection()
    print(sel)
    if sel:
        index = sel[0]
        print(index)
        list_sel()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(songlist[index])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        pause = False
        updatelabel()
        changeImage()
 
listbox.bind('<Button-1>', play_sel)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You should bind on `<<ListboxSelect>>` instead.

Comment: I tried to do that also but no change in output.

Comment: After using `<<ListboxSelect>>`, did the `print(index)` show the correct index of selected item?  What the function `list_sel()` does?  As using `<<ListboxSelect>>` works fine in my sample code based on yours.